# Shortcut to resize and move a window to the upper-left corner / upper-right corner / bottom-left corner / bottom-right corner

Tags: windows-7, display, keyboard-shortcuts

Doing <kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd> on application A and <kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd> on application B is a very cool and useful feature on Windows 7 to split the screen into 2 applications.

Now that I use it everyday, I would like even more (never happy!): is there a shortcut to **resize and move a window to the upper-left corner / upper-right corner / bottom-left corner / bottom-right corner**, so that the screen can be divided in 4 for different applications?

Something like:

<kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd> once: move and resize to left half of screen

<kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd> twice: move and resize to top-left quarter of screen

<kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd> 3 times: move and resize to bottom-left quarter of screen

would do the job:

[image]

NB: I only have 1 screen.

Comment: No, there's no built in method for that, you need to use 3rd party apps. It's already added to windows 10, where win + left / right + up / down does the trick.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Oh Win + Left then Win + Up moves it to top left quarter of screen, with Windows 10? Then maybe you can post an answer relevant for Win10 (useful for future ref).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible in windows 7, the good news you'll be able to do it in Windows 10.

Win logo key + left / right then Win logo key + up / down will move your app to left / right top / bottom corner.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find it available directly in Windows 7.

It may be possible to create an Autohotkey script for this.

I've finally found a solution with [AquaSnap](https://www.nurgo-software.com/pricing/aquasnap) (free for personal use). By default it's:

- <kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>HOME</kbd> for top left
- <kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>END</kbd> for bottom left
- <kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>PGUP</kbd> for top right
- <kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>PGDOWN</kbd> for bottom right